# Facing problem of process exited with return value 3221225725

Tags: c++

I am getting this-' process exited with return value 3221225725 ' for some of the values. I am facing problem to find where i goes wrong. Please someone help me. Here's the code-

```
    
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int binsearch(int a[],int find,int l,int u,int n);
    int main()
    {
        int a[10]={1,54,76,89,123,145,198,230,345,654};
        int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
        int find,l=0,u=n-1,x;
        cout<<"Enter number which you want to find"<<endl;
        cin>>find;
       x= binsearch(a,find,l,u,n);
       if(x==0)
       cout<<"Element is not found";
       else
       cout<<"Element is present at "<<x;
    }
    int binsearch(int a[],int find,int l,int u,int n){

        if(n==1)
        {
            if(find==a[l])
            return l;
            else
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int mid=l+u/2;
            if(a[mid]==find)
            return mid;
            else if(a[mid]<find)
            return binsearch(a,find,mid+1,u,n);
            else
            return binsearch(a,find,l,mid-1,n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your input for a [mre].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get the best result on Stack Overflow, see how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: BrahmkaranSingh: Didn't any of the answers help you to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`3221225725` is `0xC00000FD` in hex, which is Microsoft's code for a *stack overflow*.

You have written a recursive `binsearch()` function, so that's the obvious place to look for a problem.

Your recursion stops only if `n == 1` or if `a[mid]==find`. But in your code, `n` will **never** equal 1, because it is passed unchanged in each recursive call. That's a bug (there may be more, I haven't checked). So you will get a stack overflow if you enter a number that isn't in the array, because in that case `a[mid]==find` will never be true either.

My advice would be to eliminate `n` from your code. `n` is always equal to `u - l + 1`, so there is no need for a separate variable. If you need to know the value of `n`, you can always calculate it from `l` and `u`.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a number that is not found, `binsearch` will call itself over and over again until the stack overflows because your terminating condition `if(n==1)` will never be `true` since you call `binsearch` with the same `n` all the time. `n` isn't needed since you have both `l` and `u` so just make it `int n = u - l + 1;`.

`mid=l+u/2` is also incorrect. It's the same as `mid = u/2 + l`. You want `mid = (l + u) / 2`.

Also, if you search for `1` it'll return the index `0` but you treat `0` as "*not found*". Since you use a signed integer for indexing, you could return `-1` to signal that the number wasn't found.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // std::size()

int binsearch(int a[], int find, int l, int u) {
    int n = u - l + 1;

    if(n == 1) {
        if(find == a[l])
            return l;
        else
            return -1;
    } else {
        int mid = (l + u) / 2;

        if(a[mid] == find)
            return mid;
        else if(a[mid] < find)
            return binsearch(a, find, mid + 1, u);
        else
            return binsearch(a, find, l, mid - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 54, 76, 89, 123, 145, 198, 230, 345, 654};
    int l = 0, u = std::size(a) - 1, x;

    std::cout << "Enter number which you want to find\n";
    if(int find; std::cin >> find) {
        x = binsearch(a, find, l, u);
        if(x == -1)
            std::cout << "Element is not found";
        else
            std::cout << "Element is present at " << x;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```